# PHP: POST data of hidden fields error

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to pass on some hidden fields in a form from one page to another:

```
<form action=\"secondPage.php\" method=\"post\">
   <input name=\"from\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$fday/$fmonth/$fyear\">
   <input name=\"to\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$tday/$tmonth/$tyear\">
   <input type=\"submit\">
</form>
```

secondPage.php contains:

```
<?php
   $fdate = $_POST("from");
   $tdate = $_POST("to");
   echo "$fdate --- $tdate";
?>
```

I get this error on when I click submit and am redirected to secondPage.php:

```
Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\blah\secondPage.php on line 2
```

Comment: Killing Curves. Arrays in PHP are accessed with [] not () `$_POST("to");` should be `$_POST["to"];`

Answer (score 21):

PHP uses square brackets rather than parentheses for accessing arrays:

```
<?php

    $fdate = $_POST["from"];
    $tdate = $_POST["to"];
    echo "$fdate --- $tdate";

?>
```