# PHP callback contains

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, callback

I have created a class in PHP:

```
<?php

class _new_model extends model {

/**
 * NEW contruct
 */
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function newuser(){
    $password = trim($_POST['psw']);
    $password2= trim($_POST['psw1']);
    if($password === $password2){
        $hashpsw = hash('sha512', $password);
        $salt = $this->createSalt();
        $psw = hash('sha512', $salt . $hashpsw);
        $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt) VALUES (?,?,?)');
        $query->bindValue(1, $_POST['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(2, $psw, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(3, $salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        try{
            if($query->execute()){
                echo 'ჩაიწერა!';
            }else{
                echo 'მოხდა შეცდომა!';
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        echo 'პაროლები ერთმანეთს არ ემთხვევა!';
    }
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
function createSalt(){
    $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $salt = substr($text, 0, 32);
    return $salt;
}
function newlanguage(){
    $lang = trim($_POST('language'));
    $checklang = $this->checklang($lang);
    if($checklang == true){
        echo 'ეს ენა უკვე არსებობს';
    }else{
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['flag']['tmp_name'])){
            $maxsize=100000;
            $size=$_FILES['flag']['size'];
            $imgdetails = getimagesize($_FILES['flag']['tmp_name']);
            $mime_type = $imgdetails['mime'];
            // checking for valid image type
            if(($mime_type=='image/jpeg')||($mime_type=='image/gif')||($mime_type=='image/bmp')||($mime_type=='image/png')){
                // checking for size again
                if($size<$maxsize){
                    $filename=$_FILES['flag']['name'];
                    $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['flag']['tmp_name']));
                    $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO lang (name,mokled,flag,flagname,flagtype,flagsize) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
                    $query->bindValue(1, $lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindValue(2, trim($_POST('shortlang')), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindValue(3, $imgData, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                    $query->bindValue(4, $filename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindValue(5, $mime_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindValue(6, addslashes($imgdetails[3]), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    try{
                        if($query->execute()){
                            echo 'yes';
                        }else{
                            echo 'no query-ის გაშვებისას';
                        }
                    }catch (PDOException $e){
                        die($e->getMessage());
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<span class='error'>Image to be uploaded is too large..Error uploading the image!!</span>";
                }
            }else{
                echo "<span class='error'>Not a valid image file! Please upload jpeg or gif image.</span>";
            }
        }else{
            switch($_FILES['flag']['error']){
                case 0: //no error; possible file attack!
                    echo "<span class='error'>There was a problem with your upload.</span>";
                    break;
                case 1: //uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
                    echo "<span class='error'>The file you are trying to upload is too big.</span>";
                    break;
                case 2: //uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the html form
                    echo "<span class='error'>The file you are trying to upload is too big.</span>";
                    break;
                case 3: //uploaded file was only partially uploaded
                    echo "<span class='error'>The file you are trying upload was only partially uploaded.</span>";
                    break;
                case 4: //no file was uploaded
                    echo "<span class='error'>You must select an image for upload.</span>";
                    break;
                default: //a default error, just in case!
                    echo "<span class='error'>There was a problem with your upload.</span>";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param $name
 * @return bool
 */
function checklang($name){
    $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id FROM lang WHERE name = ?');
    $query->bindValue(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    try{
        $query->execute();
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}}
```

And have this HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo Domain; ?>_new/newlanguage/" name="newlanguage" method="post" id="newlanguage" >
<input type="text" name="language" id="language" placeholder="New Language">
<input type="text" name="shortlang" id="shortlang" placeholder="short name"><br>
<input type="file" name="flag" id="flag" placeholder="Flag"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>
```

When submitting the form, I get this error:

> array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 in _new_model.php on line 49
>   and on this line is written
>   return $salt;

This is the function with name create salt.  I don't understand when I'm calling newlanguage function, why it scanning the othere function?

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532481/php-post-data-of-hidden-fields-error

Answer (score 3):

`$_POST('language')` should be `$_POST['language']`.

Comment: yes. it was an mecanical error. but now I have another error.
undefined Index: flag on line 54 and 88.
on that lines are written this lines:
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['flag']['tmp_name'])){
and 
switch($_FILES['flag']['error']){

PLEASE HELP

Comment: That means they didn't upload a file in the `flag` input.

Comment: You need to test `if(isset($_FILES['flag']))` to test whether they uploaded anything.

Comment: I wiret this code
if(isset($_FILES['flag'])){
    echo 'yes';
   }else{
    echo 'no';
   }
and it esaid me NO

Comment: and when I`m writting only this code: if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['flag']['tmp_name'])){
    echo 'yes';
   }else{
    echo 'no';
   }
I`m getting same error

Comment: What don't you understand? If they didn't upload a file, the variable isn't set, so you get an error if you try to use it. That's why you have to check if it's set before you try to use it.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions that already explain what that warning means. Please do a search, it's unrelated to my answer. Please accept my answer and stop asking me unrelated questions.

Comment: please.
I have very short time to do this.
please help.
I have no time to search.

Comment: Why don't you understand? If the user uploads the file, the variable will be set. If the user doesn't upload the file, the variable is not set. So you test whether the variable is set before trying to use it. it's not complicated, any competent programmer should be able to understand it.

Comment: Phew, after almost a day of hunting for a mysterious 500 error, this was the cause. One single (sort-of) unimportant assignment used ("") instead of [""]. But yeah, I could have discovered that also in the Apache logs...